# Django DB Design and API Guidance

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my first Django app, and also my first time building an app, and I am seeking some DB and API guidance. I have an app that functions as an online directory and marketplace. What I aim to do is to provide the app to many different organizations such that the organizations have their own online directory's and marketplace's where they can manage it fully on their own, but that their data is still linked to my database so that I can then operate on the data for machine learning purposes.  This is a pretty standard/routine practice, I realize, but I am trying to wrap my head around how best to make it work. For each organization, would there just be an instance of the app which would then be a separate app or interface that connects to the original? From my newbie understanding, that is essentially what an API is, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an API, I wouldn't separate the DBs or the instances, neither make several Django apps, but I would have a dedicated `clients` model/table in the DB, which would store encoded API keys for each of your organizations.
Each client makes its request to your API by authenticating and using their API key, and the Django views answer only with the data linked to the client, as other DB tables have a foreign key to `clients`.
Sounds pretty standard and RESTful to me.

Some Django / Django REST framework modules like "Django REST Framework API Key" could probably do most of this work for you.